# How to execute adb commands in robot framework?

Tags: python, command-line, appium, adb, robotframework

I have been trying to execute adb rebooting command in robot framework to test an Android device.
(AAA shows the adb device name)

```
***Settings ***
Library     AppiumLibrary
Library  Process

*** Variables ***
${reboot} 

*** Test Cases ***
Openwatchapp
    ${reboot} =    Run Process      adb -s AAA reboot
```

However, when I run this script, this error appears.

> [FAIL] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'adb -s AAA reboot'

If there some way to solve this problem, I would like to know.

Comment: The keyword expects the ``command`` and its ``arguments`` in a list, not a string. See examples for [Specifying command and arguments](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Specifying%20command%20and%20arguments) in the library documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

I could fix this error by,
${reboot} =    Run Process      adb -s AAA reboot     shell=true

Comment: point being, your original code did not have enough spaces between command (adb) and arguments ..